# LVM_SORTITEMS sort function

Tags: winapi

LVM_SORTITEMS requires a pointer to an application defined comparison function but I was wondering instead of that where I could find the function explorer uses so to use that instead?

Comment: Um, Explorer doesn't know how to sort your items. Your ListView has a list of employees or something. Explorer doesn't know how to sort employees. Even if you had the function, it wouldn't be useful to you. Or are you asking how to sort your items the same way Explorer sorts file names? For that, use `StrCmpLogicalW`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function is application specific and Explorer provides a pointer to its own code. You cannot reuse it and even analyze it in any better way than hooking, breaking with debugger and studying disassembly.

A typical function would take item specific value, which for example, could be a pointer to some internal structure, and then compare the values from structures of the two items in question. You clicked on "Size" column, then the function would look up size for item #1 and size for item #2 and return the comparison result.

The fact that it's related to internal structures makes you unable to reuse that function the way you supposedly wanted to.